# What to use instead of ListView

Tags: android

One of the Activities in my project extended `ListView`, but since it's deprecated and I need to have a `MenuItem` showing, I don't know what to use..I can't extend `ActionBar` since I'm going to have a list of users in that `Activity`..Please help!
Neena

Comment: Better use listview inside activity, it will let you have actionbar and menu as well.

Comment: @Neena Where did you found that `ListView` is deprecated?

Comment: Hi Apurva,I need to have ListView and menu at the same time..So, you mean I extend ActionBar, then I have a listView in the class? Thnak you

Answer (score 1):

As ListView is no longer recommended by Google, you should use [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

You can get MaterialDesign video tutorials [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h57QpXp2TRg) too.

Comment: `ListView` isn't deprecated last I checked